# Encoding changes of elements in a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

Given vector `vec`:

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 0 2 0 0 0 1 1 3 0
```

I want to have another vector which encodes the changes of elements in `vec`. I would like to have this as result:

```
[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "C" "D" "D" "D" "E" "E" "F" "G"
```

If we reach `Z`, we start over with `AA`, `BB`, ..., `ZZ`, `AAA`, `BBB`, ... and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
z1[rleid(vec)]
#[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "C" "D" "D" "D" "E" "E" "F" "G"
```

or with 'z2'

```
z2[rleid(vec)]     
#[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "C" "D" "D" "D" "E" "E" "F" "G"
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
 z1[cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(vec)!=0))]
 #[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "C" "D" "D" "D" "E" "E" "F" "G"

 z1[inverse.rle(within.list(rle(vec), values <- seq_along(values)))]
```

#### data

```
vec <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0)
z1 <- unlist(sapply(1:3, function(i) do.call(paste0, 
                        expand.grid(rep(list(LETTERS), i)))))
z2 <- c(sapply(1:3, function(i) do.call(paste0, replicate(i,
                                      LETTERS, simplify=FALSE))))
```

Comment: Thanks. If we reach `Z`, we go for `AA`, `BB` and so on. I just updated my question.

Comment: @m0h3n  Updated my post as well.

Comment: @m0h3n  Can you check if this what you meant.

Comment: `z2[rleid(vec)]` (which produces my desired output) fails for `set.seed(007); vec<-rep(1:100, sample(1:3, 100, TRUE))`.

Comment: @m0h3n  It fails because `z2` have only 78 elements.  If you want to make more try with `sapply(1:4,...`

Answer (score 3):

For a larger vector:

```
set.seed(007)
x = rep(1:60, sample(1:3, 60, TRUE))
```

As I can tell, something like the following might be helpful:

```
with(rle(x), 
     rep(strrep(rep_len(LETTERS, length(lengths)), 
                (0:(length(lengths) - 1)) %/% length(LETTERS) + 1L), 
         lengths))
#  [1] "A"   "A"   "A"   "B"   "B"   "C"   "D"   "E"   "F"   "F"   "F"   "G"   "G"   "H"  
# [15] "H"   "H"   "I"   "J"   "J"   "K"   "L"   "M"   "M"   "M"   "N"   "O"   "O"   "P"  
# [29] "Q"   "Q"   "R"   "S"   "S"   "S"   "T"   "U"   "U"   "V"   "W"   "W"   "W"   "X"  
# [43] "X"   "X"   "Y"   "Y"   "Y"   "Z"   "AA"  "AA"  "BB"  "BB"  "CC"  "CC"  "CC"  "DD" 
# [57] "DD"  "EE"  "EE"  "EE"  "FF"  "GG"  "HH"  "II"  "II"  "JJ"  "JJ"  "JJ"  "KK"  "KK" 
# [71] "LL"  "LL"  "LL"  "MM"  "MM"  "MM"  "NN"  "NN"  "OO"  "OO"  "OO"  "PP"  "PP"  "QQ" 
# [85] "QQ"  "QQ"  "RR"  "RR"  "SS"  "SS"  "SS"  "TT"  "UU"  "VV"  "VV"  "VV"  "WW"  "WW" 
# [99] "WW"  "XX"  "XX"  "XX"  "YY"  "YY"  "ZZ"  "ZZ"  "ZZ"  "AAA" "AAA" "AAA" "BBB" "BBB"
#[113] "CCC" "CCC" "CCC" "DDD" "DDD" "EEE" "FFF" "GGG" "GGG" "HHH"
```

Comment: Thanks. `strrep` is not in base R, I suppose.

Comment: @m0h3n : It is in R >= 3.3.0

Comment: Oops. my bad. I use my current R rather infrequent, so not up to date.